# C# interface inheritance for property

Tags: c#

I have class like:

```
public interface IDriver
{
    string DriverName { get; }
    IDriverConfiguration Config { get; set; }
}

public interface IDriverConfiguration
{
    string DriverName { get; }
}
```

And driver class implementation:

```
public class MyDriver : IDriver
{
    public Configuration Config { get; set; }
}

public class Configuration : IDriverConfiguration
{
    public string DriverName { get; private set; }

    public bool EnableLogger { get; private set; }

    public int ArchiveLogs { get; private set; }
}
```

It seems that Config property inside `MyDriver` should return exact interface `IDriverConfiguration` instead of `DriverConfiguration` that inherits from `IDriverConfiguration`.

Is there any way to ensure that MyDriver.Config property will implement at least DriverName property?

Comment: Does this code compile?

Comment: Nope. Thats my attempt to illustrate my need.

Comment: And did you try to understand the compile error and resolve them? Members of interface must be implemented in the implementing class that's the basic rule. You might want to read about interface basics and resolve compile time issues.

Comment: Your `IDriverConfiguration` interface ensures that "MyDriver.Config" will at least implement the `DriverName` property. So just change your return type of the `Config` property to `IDriverConfiguration` and you are there...

Comment: I understand compiler messages and accept them :) And i have asked this question for advice - how to achieve specified constraints.

Comment: @Reddog but i would like to use other Configuration props inside MyDriver (lets assume it will have driver specific props).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you want the `Config` property of `MyDriver` to be a more specific type - `Configuration` instead of `IDriverConfiguration`, but writing this

```
public Configuration Config { get; set; }
```

causes your `MyDriver` class to "not implement all the interface members" and a compiler error occurs.

Note that it is *perfectly OK* for you to use `IDriverConfiguration` here, unless you have some extra code in `Configuration` that you haven't shown.

What you can do is make `IDriver` generic:

```
interface IDriver<TConfig> where TConfig: IDriverConfiguration {
    string DriverName { get; }
    TConfig Config { get; set; }
}
```

Your implementation will be like:

```
public class MyDriver : IDriver<Configuration>
{
    public Configuration Config { get; set; }
    public string DriverName => Config.DriverName;
}
```

You can do extension methods on this like this:

```
public static void MyMethod<T>(this IDriver<T> driver) where T : IDriverConfiguration {

}
```

Comment: Still doesn't compile because MyDriver doesn't have a DriverName property!

Comment: @benichka Add it in then! See my edited answer. Did it help?

Comment: I'm not the one who asked the question but this way it could be a good way to get around the problem!

Comment: Well this solved the problem i have presented! But have another :( with that construct - is there a way to write Extension Method for `IDriver<IDriverConfiguration>` - i mean extension that will be recognized for all drivers with any `Configuration` based on `IDriverConfiguration` interface

Comment: @ITMan You can write a generic extension method for `IDriver<T>`.

Comment: Lets say i have 3 drivers `DriverA : IDriver<ConfigurationA>`, `DriverB : IDriver<ConfigurationB>`, `DriverC : IDriver<ConfigurationC>`, all Configurations (A,B,C) inherit from `IDriverInterface`. I cannot write one extension method for all of them (they have different signatures)- or maybe you know the way to do that?

Comment: @ITMan You should probably start another question for that :)

Comment: @benichka i suppose i should... but that's ok for me for now.

Comment: @ITMan, "schön" :) The last edit from @Sweeper is a nice way to do it for the extension method. It can be used like that: `IDriver<Configuration> driverToExtend = (IDriver<Configuration>)driver; driverToExtend.MyMethod();`